# How to get the alias or title of the active menu item?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, joomla-api, menu-item, menu

In my template I want to give an extra class to the body of the document that will take the names of the alias of the menu item, so I can create individual styling among the pages.

But how can I get the alias or title of the active menu item ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the data of the active (current) menu item, use the following code:

```
 $app       = JFactory::getApplication(); // Access the Application Object

 $menu      = $app->getMenu(); // Load the JMenuSite Object

 $active    = $menu->getActive(); // Load the Active Menu Item as an stdClass Object
```

The **`$active`** is an object of the current menu item.

Outputting with `print_r($active)` you can have a view of all of its properties.

Example output of the above `print_r();`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 136
    [menutype] => main-menu
    [title] => Photos
    [alias] => photos
    [note] => 
    [route] => photos
    [link] => index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=157
    [type] => component
    [level] => 1
    [language] => en-US
    [browserNav] => 0
    [access] => 1
    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [show_title] => 
                    [link_titles] => 
                    [show_intro] => 
                    [info_block_position] => 
                    [show_category] => 
                    [link_category] => 
                    [show_parent_category] => 
                    [link_parent_category] => 
                    [show_author] => 
                    [link_author] => 
                    [show_create_date] => 
                    [show_modify_date] => 
                    [show_publish_date] => 
                    [show_item_navigation] => 
                    [show_vote] => 
                    [show_icons] => 
                    [show_print_icon] => 
                    [show_email_icon] => 
                    [show_hits] => 
                    [show_tags] => 
                    [show_noauth] => 
                    [urls_position] => 
                    [menu-anchor_title] => 
                    [menu-anchor_css] => 
                    [menu_image] => 
                    [menu_text] => 1
                    [page_title] => 
                    [show_page_heading] => 0
                    [page_heading] => 
                    [pageclass_sfx] => 
                    [menu-meta_description] => 
                    [menu-meta_keywords] => 
                    [robots] => 
                    [secure] => 0
                )

        )

    [home] => 0
    [img] => 
    [template_style_id] => 0
    [component_id] => 22
    [parent_id] => 1
    [component] => com_content
    [tree] => Array
        (
            [0] => 136
        )

    [query] => Array
        (
            [option] => com_content
            [view] => article
            [id] => 157
        )

)
```

To use any of the properties, you can
echo `$active->'property name';`

e.g. `echo $active->alias;`

Comment: Just a shortened way to do this :
`$menualias = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->alias;`
then in body:
`id="aliasmenu-<?php echo $menualias; ?>"`