# Get menu item by ID in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, menu-item, joomla-1.5

How do I get a menu item by ID in Joomla 3?

While converting a site from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3, I encountered this code

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication(); 
$menu = $mainframe->getMenu('mainmenu'); 
$item = $menu->getItem($Itemid);
```

How to achieve this in Joomla 3 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a big difference so far for what you are after...

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication(); 
$menu = $mainframe->getMenu(); 

// Use this if you want to get all menu items from a certain menu
$menu_items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'mainmenu');

// This is to get the specific menu item by menu item Id $itemId;
$item = $menu->getItem($itemId);
```

Check also, this Q/A, on getting the active menu item: **[How to get the alias or title of the active menu item?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/how-to-get-the-alias-or-title-of-the-active-menu-item)**