# Get menu-meta_description from menu item

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, menu-parameters, metadata, active

I need to add meta description inside a component page. That's what I tried:

```
$menu      = $app->getMenu(); // Load the JMenuSite Object
$active    = $menu->getActive(); // Load the Active Menu Item as an stdClass Object
$meta_description = $active->params->menu-meta_description;
$document->addCustomTag('<meta name="description" content="' . $meta_description . '">');
```

The result is not what I would expect:

```
<meta name="description" content="0">
```

Obviously, my content is different from "0". So, what's wrong in my code?

Comment: A relevant/insightful page for researchers: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/5198/12352

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with:

```
$meta_description = $active->params->get('menu-meta_description');
```

Here are some relevant/supporting references:

- https://www.techfry.com/joomla/how-to-access-joomla-menu-parameters-for-component
- [Getting Menu Parameters from Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4972811/2943403)
- https://www.webtechriser.com/get-any-property-of-the-active-menu-item-class-in-joomla-3/
- [How to get the alias or title of the active menu item?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5199/12352)

Comment: Your answer was flagged by the system for being low quality due to its length.  I have edited your answer to include some useful references.  It is great that you were able to self-solve and that you shared your solution with the Joomla community.  In the future, please offer a bit more insight in your answers if possible.  Providing an explanation of how/why your solution works and/or supporting resources will make your contributions much more valuable to future researchers.  Thanks for sharing.  Please take the [tour].